# weird behavior of <table>'s <tr> tag in .ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have the following code in my .ejs file.

```
        <div id="result_listings">
            <script>
                var inHTML = '<table style="border: 1px solid black">';
                var results = <%- JSON.stringify(listings) %>;
                inHTML += '<tr style="border: 1px solid black">';
                inHTML += "<th>file</th>";
                inHTML += "<th>count</th>";
                inHTML += "</tr>"; 
                
                results.forEach(function(item, index){
                    inHTML += '<tr style="border: 1px solid black>';
                    inHTML += "<td>" + index + "</td>";
                    inHTML += "<td>" + item.file + "</td>";
                    inHTML += "<td>" + item.occurances + "</td>";
                    inHTML += "</tr>";
                })    
                inHTML += "<table>";
                document.getElementById("result_listings").innerHTML = inHTML;
            </script>
        </div>
```

If the `results` array has 5 items, although the forEach loop iterates through all 5 of them, however, on the rendered page, only the content at alternate indexes (i.e, 1 and 3 in this example) is seen. Somehow, I was able to resolve this issue by replacing `inHTML += '<tr style="border: 1px solid black>';` with `inHTML += '<tr>';` but why is this issue happening?

I am a newbie to HTML/.ejs so my understanding on this is less. Can someone please explain why this behaviour is observed?

Comment: use `JSON.parse` instead of `stringlify` Please use `var results = <%- JSON.parse(listings) %>;`

Comment: @SourabhSomani OP is dumping JSON into the script, creating an object/array literal. That is perfectly fine, and your suggested fix will in fact break the template.

Comment: You didn't close the style string: `<tr style="border: 1px solid black>` (note the missing double quotes at the end)

Comment: Note however that your approach is not ideal for two separate reasons: first of all, composing HTML as a long string like that is error-prone; it's better to use a table's insertRow() / insertCell() functions for instance. However in this case you are also completely neglecting the fact that you're using EJS templates, you can build that table on the server by using a listings.forEach loop in your EJS template code.

Comment: Here's how: https://pastebin.com/DjmF5UGn (use CSS to create the table's border, not inline styles)

Comment: @ChrisG, I see the issue and totally agree with what you said. My approach was not ideal. Thanks again for helping me with this! Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :) Feel free to remove the question